# Documenting preprocessor options with Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen, c-preprocessor

I have a C++ package that allows for different behavior if the user defines different pre-processor constants.  For example, a user can use /D ALLOW_WIDE_CHAR in the makefile to change the behavior to support wide characters.

I would like to document these options with Doxygen, but Doxygen complains because there is no actual #define in the code.  It is up to the user to do that.

Adding the definition to the PREDEFINED list in the configuration file doesn't help.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

One option I found is to create an extra source file, say Doxygen.h, that is not compiled, but is added to the Doxygen file list.  This file can use #define to define those pre-processor constants.  It seems like there should be a better solution, though.

Comment: This is the best option I've seen so far, but definitely still not ideal :(